# Default Approval Workflow 'This task could not be updated at this time'

Tags: 2010, 2013, workflow, error

I have set up the default 2010 approval workflow on our 2013 systems.

The workflow works perfectly apart from an `error` which is given when a `document` is `approved/rejected`. When a user accepts from within a document opened locally they receive the error at the top of the window in a yellow bar.

> 'This task could not be updated at this time'

The users response, however, is communicated with the server as the workflow moves correctly onto the next stage. My `issue` is more down to `user experience`, if they are seeing this error they are going to think the workflow has failed, which is actually not the case.

Any information on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the permissions on the task list associated with the workflow. Workflows have two related lists: one for tasks, one for workflow history. If the list you have the approval workflow is not inheriting permissions from the parent, check the permissions on these two lists.